# ML.Net Data Loader (Memory)

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

The ML.Net examples which I've found all use TextLoader to load data via csv or the like.

**how would one go about loading data in to a trainer without TextLoader,**

I am streaming a lot of data to a List

```
var pipeline = new LearningPipeline
{
    new Microsoft.ML.Data.TextLoader(_datapath).CreateFrom<Match>(useHeader: true, separator: ','),
    …
```

Is there an implementation that takes in T[] .. **continuesly writing csv files to disk seems like a lot of unnessesary IO** from a continues point of view, especially if the training function locks the files. meaning multiple files per active training instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the existing `LearningPipeline` APIs, `CollectionDataSource` can be used to train on data that is already in memory:

```
var pipeline = new LearningPipeline();
var data = new List<IrisData>() {
    new IrisData { SepalLength = 1f, SepalWidth = 1f, PetalLength=0.3f, PetalWidth=5.1f, Label=1},
    new IrisData { SepalLength = 1f, SepalWidth = 1f, PetalLength=0.3f, PetalWidth=5.1f, Label=1},
    new IrisData { SepalLength = 1.2f, SepalWidth = 0.5f, PetalLength=0.3f, PetalWidth=5.1f, Label=0}
};
var collection = CollectionDataSource.Create(data);

pipeline.Add(collection);
pipeline.Add(new ColumnConcatenator(outputColumn: "Features",
    "SepalLength", "SepalWidth", "PetalLength", "PetalWidth"));
pipeline.Add(new StochasticDualCoordinateAscentClassifier());
var model = pipeline.Train<IrisData, IrisPrediction>();
```

Sample taken from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/machinelearning/master/test/Microsoft.ML.Tests/CollectionDataSourceTests.cs).

With the new upcoming ML.NET APIs, this will change and new samples will be provided to show how to do this.

Note: I am on the ML.NET team.

Comment: This is no longer the case, as it's obsolete and doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [ml.net train model input from string instead of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50793621/ml-net-train-model-input-from-string-instead-of-a-file)

You can use CollectionDataSource, introduced in version 0.2 of ML.NET.